# Post feed different from older graph API to new

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created an app in Facebook a while back to get a feed from a specific clients page. The feed looks something like so:

[image]

I am trying to do the same with a new client and now the feed looks very different:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I can do to get the old feed style back, because it gives so much more information than the new API versions feed.

The older app is version 2.0 and the newer one is 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed is that with all Graph API request above v2.3, you need to specify the fields you want to have returned from the Graph API. Otherwise only a small standard set of fields is returned.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> **Declarative Fields**
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.